# Java CodingBat array to list

Tags: java, arrays, list

Here is the question;

http://codingbat.com/prob/p153748

Given two `int`s, each in the range 10..99, return true if there is a digit that appears in both numbers, such as the 2 in 12 and 23. (Note: division, e.g. `n/10`, gives the left digit while the `%` "mod" `n%10` gives the right digit.)

```
shareDigit(12, 23) → true
shareDigit(12, 43) → false
shareDigit(12, 44) → false
```

My attempt :D

```
public boolean shareDigit(int a, int b) {
      boolean answer = false;
      int left = a/10;
      int right = a % 10;
      if(Arrays.asList(b).contains(left) ||Arrays.asList(b).contains(right)){
          answer = true;
      }
      return answer;
}
```

Not sure why it's never returning true, also this is the first time I've used array as List so feel free to add tips :D

Comment: Do you know what `Arrays.asList` does? And why do you think it will help you here?

Comment: hmmm why list... :) well then why not try with this (b+"").contains(left)

Comment: @tom I'm not completely familiar but this was what was told for me to do when I wanted to check if an element was in an array.

Comment: This is right, but `b` is not an array.

Comment: omg you're right I read it wrong for so long haha

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList(b)` produces an array the contains one element - the number `b`. Therefore, unless `b` is a single number digit (which it is not, according to your description), no single digit of `a` can be contained in that array.

Just split the second number `b` into two digits, as you did with `a`, and compare the two digits of `a` to the two digits of `b` (4 comparisons at most).